# Error en Travis CI(proyecto angular)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, travis-ci

Al hacer `npm audit fix` y `ng build --prod`, me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Date: 2019-04-25T10:28:19.462Z
Hash: 0ac4170b0a4d66eddd2d
Time: 123639ms
chunk {0} runtime.26209474bfa8dc87a77c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.a10bbd91cb3dfa03228a.js (main) 1.51 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.4c4f8ef040147bb3e499.js (polyfills) 58.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.62656b300958c816df87.css (styles) 165 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.8123f3f0326e7d6f45d3.js (scripts) 633 kB [entry] [rendered]
ERROR in ./node_modules/solid-file-client/dist/browser/solid-file-client.bundle.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'null' in '/home/travis/build/Arquisoft/dechat_es4a/node_modules/solid-file-client/dist/browser'
The command "ng build --prod" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "10.15"
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install
  - npm install --save howler
  - npm audit fix
script: 
  - ng build --prod
after_success:
  - node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js src\test\dechatCucumber\features -r src\test\dechatCucumber\features\step_definitions
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Supongo que es algun tipo de libreria que me falta por instalar, alguie ha tenido un problema parecido o sabría subsanar el error anterior ¿?

Comment: Seria de ayuda que subieras tu .travis.yml, efectivamente es por falta de una libreria

Comment: Instalaste algun solid-file-client? Que hay en tu package.json? El error es raro, primero dice que no encuentra un modulo, pero despues dice tiene un problema con un valor null. ng build funciona pero ng build --prod no?

Comment: sisiis instale: npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install
npm install --save howler
npm install solid-auth-client
npm install solid-file.client
npm audit fix

Comment: Falto poner ```npm install solid-auth-client``` y ```npm install solid-file-client``` , fijate en mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258974/39913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el resultado final con el que me pasa ya Travis es el siguiente: (travis.yml)

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "10.15"
before_script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli
  - npm install
  - npm install --save howler
  - npm install solid-auth-client
  - npm install solid-file-client@0.4.9
script: 
  - ng build --prod
after_success:
  - node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js src\test\dechatCucumber\features -r src\test\dechatCucumber\features\step_definitions
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Answer (score 2):

En `before_script` asegurate de instalar todo lo que instalaste en tu computadora.

#### Resultado

```
language: node_js 
node_js: - "10.15"

before_script: 
  - npm install -g @angular/cli 
  - npm install 
  - npm install --save howler
  - npm install solid-auth-client
  - npm install solid-file-client // Es solid-file.client o solid-file-client?
  - npm audit fix 

script: 
  - ng build --prod 

after_success: 
  - node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js src\test\dechatCucumber\features -r src\test\dechatCucumber\features\step_definitions 
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Comment: Ha habido un problemilla que m di cuenta ahora, al instalar npm install solid-file client usa una version 5.0, en cambio si hago la version anterior funciona:npm install solid-file-client@0.4.9